# No calls to mocked object in scala using powermock

Tags: java, scala, powermock

I am trying to use power mock in scala.

Class I want to test

```scala
class Operations {
  def write(s: String): Unit = {
     val customWriter = new CustomWriter()
     customWriter.write(s)
  }
}
```

Class I want to mock

```scala
class CustomWriter {
  def write(s: String): Unit = {
     //do something
  }
}
```

My spec file

```scala
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar.mock
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSpec, PrivateMethodTester}

@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[Operations]))
class PowerMockTest extends FunSpec {

  describe("Using power mock") {
    it("check constructor call") {
      val ops = new Operations()
      val mocked = mock[CustomWriter]
      PowerMockito.whenNew(classOf[CustomWriter]).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mocked)
      ops.write("Write Me")
      PowerMockito.verifyNew(classOf[CustomWriter]).withNoArguments()
    }
  }
}
```

How ever the tests are failing with the stacktrace

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Wanted but not invoked customWriter();
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I even tried verifying the method call on mocked object, still no luck

```scala
Mockito.verify(mocked).write("Write me")
```

Please help me understand what am I missing here

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Did you verify that Operations#write method's customWriter instance is the same 'mocked' instance? (if not, maybe something is wrong with the `whenNew` directive)

Comment: Yes, the type is same and verified

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missing `CustomWriter` from the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.

The need to use Powermock can be a sing that you're doing something wrong. Maybe you can change your approach so that you can test it with Mockito.

If you have control over the `Operations` class, you can maybe pass the `CustomWriter` instance instead of instantiating it inside the method.